# To draw a truncated solid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am not able to find error in the following Latex code.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in
{
1/{(0 ,0)}/{$wz^2$}/left,
 2/{( 2, 0)}/{$w^2z$}/right,
 3/{(1 ,.7)}/{$yw^2$}/left,
 4/{(3.2,1.5)}/{$y^2w$}/right,
5/{(-1.2 ,1.5)}/{$xy^2$}/left,
 6/{(-0.3,2.5)}/{$x^2y$}/below,
 7/{(2.3,2.5)}/{$xy^2$}/below,
8/{(3.2 ,3.5)}/{$yz^2$}/right,
9/{(-1.2 ,3.5)}/{$xy^2$}/left,
10/{(0 ,5)}/{$xz^2$}/left,
 11/{(2 ,5)}/{$x^2z$}/right,
12/{(1 ,4.3)}/{$x^2w$}/right,
}
\node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
 \draw (1) -- (2) -- (4) -- (8) -- (11) -- (10) -- (9) -- (5) -- (1);
\draw (1) -- (3) -- (12) -- (10);
\draw (11) -- (12);
\draw (3) -- (2);
\draw[dashed] (9) -- (6) -- (7) -- (8);
\draw[dashed] (5) -- (6);
\draw[dashed] (7) -- (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: delete comma after last item in list: `12/{(1 ,4.3)}/{$x^2w$}/right}`.

Comment: This post no longer makes sense: The original problem, a syntax error as pointed out by @Zarko, has been removed from the post by an edit.

Comment: sorry sir, I have re-edited it.